# Adaptec 8405E RAID 1 extremely slow expansion (1% per day)

Tags: raid, raid1, adaptec

Our RAID 1 is being expanded from 4 TB to 8 TB. The GUI status looks like this:

[image]

[image]

The progress happens by about 1% per day. At the same time, the server is quite slow. This seems like an extremely slow rate of progress. This amounts to 4TB/100/86400 = 460KB/s. I'd expect the RAID controller to merely write zeroes sequentially  to the new segments which should happen much faster.

I do not believe that the server is otherwise so loaded as to cause such a massive slowdown.

According to SMART data, the disks are new and healthy.

What could be a reason for this and is it possible to speed this up? Limping along like this for about 100 days does not seem very desirable to me...

Comment: Are you expanding from 2x 4 TB disks to 4x 4 TB disks?

Comment: We first successfully went from 2x4 TB to 2x8 TB by replacing and rebuilding. This is done. Now, we are adding the additional 4 TB by expanding. @shodanshok

Comment: For future visitors: This server has successfully expanded by now. It spent 3 month doing that (!). This is obviously a disaster and I never found out what caused this.